# c# - deserialization of specific JSON

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have JSON text with structure like this:

```
{
  "324523":{"a":1345, "b":2344},
  "134565":{"a":1642, "b":2322},
  "123426":{"a":1556, "b":2674},
  ...
}
```

Is it possible to make .NET classes to deserialize such JSON? It looks like a Dictionary, but DataContractJsonSerializer doesn't deserialize this.

Comment: The JSON you posted is very weird.. Are you absolutely sure it's like this? It's an `object` with `properties` named `324523`, `134565`, ... - this is not a list or even a dictionary.

Comment: Yes, it's weird JSON. I got it from btc-e.com API.

Comment: 324523, 134565, 123426, ... - are elements of list

Comment: But the JSON you posted is not a list. An array (or list) in JSON is wrapped in `[]`, your JSON is an object wrapped in `{}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try JSON.Net, which you can obtain from NuGet, or from the [JSON.Net website](http://james.newtonking.com/json).

Deserializing:

```
var jsonValues = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(someJsonString);
var pocoValue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourClass>(someJsonString);
// or as a dictionary:
var dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<MyClass>>(someJsonString);
```